# Call the script after disconnecting from server

Tags: shell-script, ssh, function

I have a script I made for work that will call a function that takes an argument. I use the arguments to `ssh` into our servers. My question is: Is there a way to call the method so that if/when I get disconnected from our servers, It will automatically call the script? So for example, I can `ssh` into one of our servers. We have a `reverse-ssh` tunnel set up so after an hour the connection closes. I want it so that after the disconnection, the script will be called again prompting for a hostname.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Provide hostname: "
read host

createSSHFunction()
{
    arg1=$1
    ssh $host
}
createSSHFunction $host
```

Comment: *"I want it so that after the disconnection, **the script** will be called again prompting for a hostname."* -> You're not asking to call a **function** recursively then.

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion, I made an edit to the question

Comment: Why was this question downvoted???!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop infinitely, but prevent the script from running again when you are done.

```
while ((1)); do script.sh; sleep 3; done
```

The three second sleep gives you an opportunity to break the loop.  When you're done with ssh, exit.  In three seconds, the script will start again.  If you don't want that to happen, <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> will stop the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is rarely the answer to anything :-)

What you are trying to do can be done via a simple loop

```
while :; do
  ssh $host
done
```

Whenever `ssh` exits, the script will go to the next iteration of the loop, and re-execute it.

In `while :`, the `:` is a noop command that always returns a true value, so the `while` will never end. If you need some way of terminating the loop, you'll need to figure out what that criteria is, and test for it.

Comment: I tried that and I get an infinite loop...

Comment: Any recursion would also be infinite ;)

Comment: @ryekayo that's what you asked for, "when I get disconnected from our servers, It will automatically call the function". If you want to break the loop, you need to specify criteria for doing so.

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question a bit further